# How to avoid cross origin issues when prefetching svg files that are loaded with a request?

Tags: javascript, svg, amazon-s3, fetch, prefetch

I try to prefetch some `.svg` files and then to request them and insert them into the DOM.

looks like prefetching succeeds but the request fails with cross-origin issues because the prefetch tag:

`<link rel="prefetch" href="e11efd5ca0332441cf9887c504d647ae.svg?source=isvg">`

does not demand cross-origin headers and when we make a reqeust from JS we get the cached response without them:

`fetch('e11efd5ca0332441cf9887c504d647ae.svg?source=isvg', {cross-origin-headers})`

I use Amazon S3 to store my files but i guess this is a more general issue.

here is the prefetch:
[image: prefetching]

here is the fetch:
[image: fetching]

Comment: Have you tried `<link crossorigin="anonymous" rel="prefetch" href="e11efd5ca0332441cf9887c504d647ae.svg?source=isvg">`?

Comment: good point. the reason is that we want to support ie and edge, and this attribute is not supported there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Browser_compatibility

Comment: OK, well, there’s no way other than using the crossorigin attribute to cause browsers to do a CORS-enabled fetch for a link element. If the link element has no crossorigin attribute, the HTML spec requires browsers to use the (default) no-cors request mode, and there’s no way to get around that.